# How to do Push Notification in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am working on Xamarin forms. I had been searching for Push notification in Xamarin forms, some said there is no such implementation for Xamarin forms but there are Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android. I am a newbie I may miss many development news on this subject.

I would like to know:

1) Is there any latest development for Xamarin forms for Push Notification?
2) Any sample app to learn from , any tutorial for xamarin form?
3) What are requirements to build this kind of app, what SDK or tools required.

Please help

Comment: Are you talking about Azure Push notifcations ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are talking about Azure push notifications.
If that's the case there is a detailed Xamarin guide to help you for this matter:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/push-notifications/azure/

Also checkout the sidebar since that also include interesting posts about this service.

Good Luck

Comment: Would you know what Tools or SDK to create the app? I need to use Google Firebase ?

Comment: Normally everything can be found in the guide, But yes you indeed need Firebase cloud messaging, but that's also explained in the guide

Answer (score 1):

Push Notifications have slightly different requirements for each platform. You will need to write platform specific code for each of the platforms you wish to target in your Xamarin.Forms App.

The best way to achieve this is with a `DependencyService`. There is a great overview of how to do this with a number of examples in the Xamarin.Forms [guides](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/).

Unfortunately one of the examples is not for Push Notifications. However, there is a great (free) [book](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter5/concepts/) that contains loads of useful walkthroughs and examples for Xamarin.Forms including a chapter (5) on Push Notifications. There are code recipes for Android, iOS and Windows which should provide you with what you need.

For SDKs/tools I would recommend using an [Azure Notification Hub](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/notification-hubs/), this can be integrated with each of the major platforms notifications services:

- APNS for iOS
- Firebase for Android
- WNS for Windows

Once configured, this will allow you to send the same notifications to multiple users without worrying which platform they are on.