# How to send request from server side (asp.net web api / mvc ) to xamarin forms app?

Tags: asp.net, xamarin, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms, signalr

i need recommendations from you. I have a project which use web api back end and xamarin forms. Xamarin forms is multi-user apps. Depends to user location it sends post or get request to server side and some actions occur. But what to do when i need to send something to xamarin app from web api without request from it ?????? I mean when some event happen i need to send something like push notification to specific user in xamarin app ???? (like uber send notification to drivers or riders). How to implement this ???? i was thinking to use SignalR but not sure....please help ??? thnks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do Push Notification in Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44908688/how-to-do-push-notification-in-xamarin-forms)

Comment: i don't need push notification, all i need to send request from web api to xamarin

Comment: As mobile application can be in background or killed by the the mobile OS, the only way to make sure that the "request" will hit the "xamarin" part is to send a push notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to implement real time communication (when the app is **open or running in the background**), you could use `SignalR`. However, `SignalR` won't allow you to have real notifications mechanism (i.e. getting a push notification when the app is closed and click on it to open the app). Using SignalR, your app UI would get updated if app is open but that's it because `SignalR` relies on active connections.

If you really want to implement push notifications, you should check the following links:

- [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/firebase-cloud-messaging)

> Using FCM, app servers can send messages to a single device, to a
>   group of devices, or to a number of devices that are subscribed to a
>   topic. A client app can use FCM to subscribe to downstream messages
>   from an app server (for example, to receive remote notifications).

- If needed: [How to use it with Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/push-notifications/azure#android_register_fcm)

Hope it helps!

Comment: quick question: i need to recieve message or notification as popup with two buttons (submin, cancel) and one text area for input and then send it back to server :) is it possible to archive it with push notification ???? thank you

Comment: @RostyslavZhovnir Again, it really depends if you NEED notifications when the app is closed or not.. If having the app open is mandatory to get these notifications then `SignalR` is enough. Otherwise, Firebase will push you a notification even if the app is closed -> you click on it to open the correct page where you display two buttons + a text area -> implement click on buttons that will send data back to the server and close the app. It should be also possible to customize the UI of a push notification (i.e. adding a text entry and a send button) but I have no experience about that.

Comment: @RostyslavZhovnir please accept answer if it helps. Regards.